# Find the shape of the column (Ordinary differential equations exercise)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Imagine a vertical column supporting a certain weight at the top, $P_0$. This, produces a pressure on the top base of $\frac{P_0}{S_0}$, where $S_0$ is the area of the top base. Now, at a distance $x$ from the base, the section of the column (which has area $S(x)$ for some function $S$) is now supporting a pressure given by the following formula:
>
> $$P(x)=\frac{P_0+\delta\int_0^xS(t)dt}{S(x)}$$
>
> Where $\delta$ is a constant called the *specific weight*. Now, deduce the shape of the column knowing that it's a surface of revolution, and that the pressure $P(x)$ at a distance $x$ of the base is of the form $kx+\frac{P_0}{S_0}$, where $k$ is a positive constant such that $\delta\geq k$

This exercise is supposed to be modelized by using ordinary differential equations, and the hint we were given is to use separation of variables to solve it, however, I just can't even see how to start attacking it. If I understood it properly, it's asking us to find the outline/profile of the column, is this correct?

Since the column is obtained revolving a certain curve, we know the horizontal sections of the column, which have area $S(x)$, are all circles, and so the area is $\pi r_x^2$. I think the solution would be to obtain such values $r_x$, and then get the curve based on those values (which should be enough to calculate it).

This sure seems like a initial value problem, where we have our independent variable $x$ ranging from $0$ to the height of the column, our dependant variable, which I think it's $P(x)$, or maybe $S(x)$. I'm not sure if this is correct, since we are given two initial values, $S(0)=S_0$, and $P(0)=\frac{P_0}{S_0}$ (both the area and the pressure at the top, of course).

I guess I should mention we've barely seen any theory in a couple weeks of classes, so just a simple solution by separation of variables should do it. Thanks in advance.